# Can I run a Firebird stored procedure from a batch file, or is there an ISQL equivalent

Tags: batch-file, firebird, isql

I want to run a Firebird stored procedure from a batch file or similar on a desktop. The stored procedure contains insert statements and update statements with if possible parameters that I would like to pass.

Any ideas or other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Use mghie's advice on how to call EXECUTE PROCEDURE from an SQL script. If your stored procedure happens to use "suspend" then combine with Hugues Van Landeghem's (because in that case you need to FOR SELECT)

Answer (score 1):

There is a Firebird isql tool, it even has a link in the start menu group. You can use this in your script. For the syntax see for example [Stefan Heymann's site](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/isql.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also try the [EXECUTE BLOCK](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-execblock.html) syntax

Comment: +1 because without EXECUTE BLOCK you're limited to simple operations (INSERT / DELETE / UPDATE & Metadata Manipulation)